# Importing multiple R files into list and storing each element as file name to retrieve

Tags: r

I'm wanting to import multiple rds files within a certain folder into a list, and store these dataframes in the list as their filename. For example, let's say that we have two files within a folder: "apples.rds" and "pears.rds".

To import them I've got:

```
df_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.rds") %>%
  map(readRDS)
```

But these are stored as df_list[1] and df_list[2], when I want them to be df_list[apples] and df_list[pears] so that I can retrieve these dataframes later by their name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
flist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rds$")

df_list <- setNames(lapply(flist, readRDS), tools::file_path_sans_ext(flist))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names(df_list) <- list.files(pattern = "*.Rds")
```